# Remove extraneous JS files from Magento Modern Theme - ccard.js is on every page but only used at checkout

Tags: javascript, xml, magento, external

Magento is a dog. I think that much is clear. My task is to make it a greyhound vs the poodle it now is. To do this I have to remove some JS files that are loading on every page and only load them on necessary pages.

One example is lib/ccard.js. This is a credit card verification script that is only used on the onepagecheckout billing.phtml file. I can comment out the line in page.xml to remove it from all pages but I can't figure out the valid XML to load it into the onepagecheckout area.

I added a line at checkout.xml under the "One page checkout main layout" area but that just crashes the cart.

```
<reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
    </reference>
```

If anyone can specifically tell me how to do this that would be wonderful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing what you're attempting to do.  Yes Magento is large and there are some optimizations that can be made, however removing JS files on pages you feel they may not be needed may cause you problems down the road.  If you have a 3rd party plugin or do a Magento upgrade that requires that specific JS file to be on a particular page, but it isn't loaded you'll run into errors.

Making Magento run faster starts with server optimizations.  If you have a server not configured to run Magento properly, it's going to load slow no matter what you do to the frontend files.

I recommend just combining the JS files in the configuration under **System > Configuration > Developer > JavaScript Settings** and set **Merge JavaScript files** to `Yes`.

---

To answer your question as to why your XML reference isn't working, it's because the method `addJs` is a method belonging to the `head` block, not the root.  You would want to use this:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Thank you Axel! First of all thank you for answering the question even against your best judgement. I appreciate this type of response: advice + requested answer. I do use the Merge options for JS/CSS for production but during development it is off. Your code worked successfully for me and I promise not to use it judiciously. The ccard.js was really bugging me as it made an extra call to the server and was taking 455ms to process the request with Magento & browser caches turned off. Testing now for other areas where it is required (multiple address checkout, possibly admin).

Comment: Not a problem, I'm happy to help either way :)